# How to use common model class for retrofit and squidb

Tags: android, retrofit, yahoo-squidb

In my android app, I am reading data from the server in JSON format and storing it local SQLite db.

I am using retrofit and Gson for reading and converting Json into objects.

For e.g.

```
@Parcel
public class PersonResponse {

    @SerializedName("name")
    public String name;
}
```

I am using Yahoo Squidb as ORM.

```
@TableModelSpec(className = "Person", tableName = "people")
public class PersonSpec {

    @ColumnSpec(name="name", defaultValue="")
    public String name;

  public static Person create(PersonResponse obj) {

    return new Person(obj){...};
  }
}
```

Trouble is I can't use a single object for both. Therefore, it has become pain to maintain two similar pojos.

I have to now convert from PersonResponse to Person

```
Person p = Person.create(obj_person_response);
```

Has anyone implemented it. Please suggest.

Comment: did you find a solution?